# No answer after Interview

Tags: interviewing

I was interview on 21/01 for a Graduate Engineering position at London. It was for a huge company (Arup), but since then I have no answer. The day of the interview, I was told that I would receive an answer within two weeks. However, this never happened so I decided to send an email, 4 weeks after the interview, and I was told: "we have some final interview over the next to weeks, and we will let you know by this point". Still waiting for their answer.

What do you think I should do? And what are the possibilities that I am not rejected already?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't pin your hopes on this company. Keep looking, and good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately all too common, in the US at least.

There are any number of possible explanations.  After two months, the most likely one is that someone else got the job.  It is less that excellent etiquette on their part, and there is nothing you can do about it.

About all you can do is continue interviewing with other companies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the company name you mentioned or general employment practices in the UK, but it definitely is not a good impression to make on their future employees, by not following up with them when they say they will do. Consider as a blessing disguise that you are not getting on board with them. If they are that tardy to forget small things like that, before you are hired, what could happen when you are on board and have a problem with something.

My guess, someone at HR who is assigned to giving the bad news to people who are rejected, is not cut out for giving-the-bad-news kind of job. As the other answer suggested, don't lose sleep over actions of this company or lack thereof and keep searching for a job elsewhere.